# What is XMl Parsing

Tags: xml

I am working on Parsing right now, So can anybody please through some light pertaining to what XMl Parsing is basically being done and I would appreciate it greatly if somebody who knows it can give me any example for the same.

Thanks in Advance,
john

Comment: Please specify in which language you are trying to parse xml...
Check this http://xml.silmaril.ie/authors/parsers/
Try out something and get back!!!
All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML parsing is the operation to validate an XML document. You can do it using a softaware like `EDITIX` that you can download it from http://www.editix.com/download.html it's free and also you can use it to create XML documents, DTDs and XML schemas

Answer (score 1):

XML parsing is the task of taking some text, formatted according to the rules of XML, and turning it into a data structure.

As for examples, they depend a lot on the language you are using and the libraries you choose.

In Perl, you might:

```
  my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);
```